# Constraint constraints/compute.storageResourceUseRestrictions violated for project GCP

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine

I am getting error while creating VM instance in GCP.

Constraint constraints/compute.storageResourceUseRestrictions violated for project.

Constraint constraints/compute.storageResourceUseRestrictions violated for project . projects/debian-cloud/global/images/debian-9-stretch-v20180401 can't be used within your organization.

Comment: Same Here! Waiting for a clue...

Comment: "Message: Instance 'INSTANCE_NAME' creation failed: Constraint constraints/compute.storageResourceUseRestrictions violated for project PROJECT_ID. projects/cos-cloud/global/images/cos-beta-60-9592-65-0 can't be used within organizations/ORG_ID."

Comment: I am checking on the issue, and it seems to be happening when creating a Dataproc clusters or Dataflow jobs. Is this the case or you guys get the error when creating regular VMs?

Comment: @suren I got data while creating usual VM's Instances in auto-scaled instance group

Answer (score 1):

Probably an administrator in your organization has set up [compute resource restrictions](https://cloud.google.com/resource-manager/docs/organization-policy/org-policy-constraints). It's intended to allow individuals in an organization creating resources to be restricted to a list of preset approved images. Likely the constraint isn't built in such a way that 'v20180401' or the stretch keyword are approved.

Answer (score 0):

This error is related to violating [constraint rules](https://cloud.google.com/resource-manager/docs/organization-policy/overview#constraints) in your project. Looks like your organization has a policy to block users outside of google.com from access to Google-owned images. Your issue is caused by your [organization policy](https://cloud.google.com/resource-manager/docs/organization-policy/org-policy-constraints) constraint applied to this project.

This issue occurred on April 19’18 to multiple users due to an organization policy change that was applied to the google.com organization. This blocked users outside of google.com from access to Google-owned images. The change resulted in failures to create Google Compute Engine VM instances, thereby causing errors in creating Dataflow jobs, Dataproc clusters and GKE nodes. Google Engineers rolled back the policy change at 19:13 US/Pacific. Following the rollback, the error rate immediately subsided and the services fully recovered.

**NOTE :** When using this constraint, users must have Cloud IAM permissions, and they must not be restricted by the constraint to access the resource.